# openMP syntax error

Tags: for-loop, openmp

I am using openMP to parallelize for loop. However, the compiler fails to build with: "unrecognized OpenMP #pragma". The output shows it occurs on "for" keyword.
I have already enabled openMP support in language (visual studio). If I try compiling with any other pragmas e.g single critical it seems to work fine. But it can't recognize "for".

```
#pragma omp parallel for

                        for (int i = 0; i < method_cnt; i++)
                        {
                          //Perform calculation
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. `for` and `parallel for` must be followed by a for-loop and not by a block:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
                {   <--- wrong
                    for (int i = 0; i < method_cnt; i++)
                    {
                      //Perform calculation
                    }
                }   <--- wrong
```

The correct syntax is:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int i = 0; i < method_cnt; i++)
                {
                  //Perform calculation
                }
```

Comment: Sorry my actual code doesn't include those brackets. I have edited my post.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the source code from somewhere else? Make sure that there are no invisible characters in the pragma directive or somewhere on the next line. Delete the pragma line and retype it again. If necessary, examine the source file with a hex editor. Also, provide more context (i.e. several lines before the `#pragma`).